# Output showing 0 for random() function

Tags: python-3.x, random, random-seed

So, I have this battle scenario here:

```py
 def band_attack():
        global new_ship
        print('Bandits attack!')
        s.sleep(1)
        c = r.random()
        if c < 0.5:
            print('Bandits missed!')
        elif 0.5 < c < 0.7:
            c = r.random()
            new_ship = new_ship - int(c)
            print('Your ship was hit for', c, 'damage!')
            print('Your ship now has', int(new_ship), 'health!')
        else:
            new_ship = new_ship - int(c)
            print('Critical strike! You were hit for', c, 'damage!')
            print('Your ship now has', int(new_ship), 'health!')
        if new_ship <= 0:
            print('You\'ve been destroyed!')
        else:
            Fight.band_fight()
```

`Fight` is the class holding all the battle functions, `r` is the `random` module, `s` is the `time` module, `band_attack` is a function where you attack.

I want the damage obviously to be whole numbers above `0`, hence why I turn the random function output to an integer.

It should be outputting a number greater than `0`, or if it is `0`,  should just be a miss, but I'm clearly missing something. Maybe someone else can figure out what I'm missing?

Comment: did you want to use `round` instead of `int`? `int(random())` will always be `0` --  `round(random())` will be `0` or `1`. maybe use `randint` instead?

Comment: Why change the meaningful namespaces `random` and `time` to `r` and `s`, respectively, and then had to explain what those meaningless names mean? Stick with the defaults and your code will be easier to read.

Comment: that would probably make more sense, thank you @hiroprotagonist

Comment: @accdias it's just easier for me since i use those modules so much, and last time i asked a question i had someone ask what the alias was for, figure i'd skip the middle man and explain first.

Comment: actually, @hiroprotagonist , the issue with using randint is i dont think you can seed that? i'm using seeds throughout the code.

Comment: @rhozagi, From [PEP20, The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): _"Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!"_ :-)

Comment: `randint()` will respect your `seed()`

Comment: @rhozagi As mentioned in the comments and my answer `seed` will work with the other functions. Please let us know if the solution works for you (and if it helped accept an answer)

Answer (score 3):

The call to [`random.random()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.random) will always return a floating-point number in the range `[0.0, 1.0)` as per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.random).

When you cast the result to `int` (by calling the `int(c)`), you are asking for the integer part of that `float` which is always equal to zero for floats in that range.

There are two ways to fix this: either multiply the result of [`random.random()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.random) by `10` or use the [`random.randint(a, b)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint), which returns a random integer `N`, such that `a <= N <= b`. You will need to adjust your conditions accordingly.

You mentioned in the comments that you are worried about seeding the random number generator when using [`random.randint(a, b)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) but since the seed function affects the module's random number generator itself all functions (randint, choice, randrange) will behave as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The `random()` function from the random module (which I assume is what you named r) returns a float between 0 and 1. You can't pass a float into `int()`. The best alternative would be to use either `randint(x, y)` (where x and y denote the range in which you want your random damage to be), or stick to `random()` and mulitply it by the upper limit of that intended range.